# Libgdx: How can I load assets after screen has already rendered?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have implemented the loading screen from [this example](https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen) on my Loading Screen that is a child of Game. This is how my asset init method and Screen class looks like. My init method in assets loads classes that contain my AtlasRegion. I have tested that this method is what makes my screen load a black screen as it loads a lot of resources.

```
    public void init (AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
    // set asset manager error handler
    assetManager.setErrorListener(this);

    assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS, TextureAtlas.class);
    assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_UI, TextureAtlas.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();

    TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS);
    TextureAtlas atlasUi = assetManager.get(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_UI);

    //font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/font.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("data/font.png"), false);

    clickSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/sounds/click.wav"));

    // create game resource objects
    fonts = new AssetFonts(assetManager);
    skins = new AssetSkins();
    background = new AssetBackgroundImage();
    cards = new AssetCards(atlas);
    cardimages = new AssetImages(atlas);
    cardsjson = new AssetList();
    suitimages = new AssetSuitImages(atlas);
}
```

This is my Loading Screen class:

```
    public class LoadingScreen extends AbstractGameScreen implements Disposable {

    private Stage stage;

    private Image logo;
    private Image loadingFrame;
    private Image loadingBarHidden;
    private Image screenBg;
    private Image loadingBg;

    private float startX, endX;
    private float percent;

    private Actor loadingBar;

    public LoadingScreen(CardGame game) {
        super(game);
    }

    public InputProcessor getInputProcessor () {
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // Tell the manager to load assets for the loading screen
        game.manager.load("data/images-ui/loading/loading.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
        // Wait until they are finished loading
        game.manager.finishLoading();

        // Initialize the stage where we will place everything
        stage = new Stage();

        // Get our textureatlas from the manager
        TextureAtlas atlas = game.manager.get("data/images-ui/loading/loading.pack", TextureAtlas.class);

        // Grab the regions from the atlas and create some images
        logo = new Image(atlas.findRegion("libgdx-logo"));
        loadingFrame = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-frame"));
        loadingBarHidden = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-bar-hidden"));
        screenBg = new Image(atlas.findRegion("screen-bg"));
        loadingBg = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-frame-bg"));

        // Add the loading bar animation
        Animation anim = new Animation(0.05f, atlas.findRegions("loading-bar-anim") );
        anim.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_REVERSED);
        loadingBar = new LoadingBar(anim);

        // Or if you only need a static bar, you can do
        // loadingBar = new Image(atlas.findRegion("loading-bar1"));

        // Add all the actors to the stage
        stage.addActor(screenBg);
        stage.addActor(loadingBar);
        stage.addActor(loadingBg);
        stage.addActor(loadingBarHidden);
        stage.addActor(loadingFrame);
        stage.addActor(logo);

        // Add everything to be loaded, for instance:
        Assets.instance.init(game.manager);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // Set our screen to always be XXX x 480 in size
        //width = 480 * width / height;
        //height = 480;
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);

        // Make the background fill the screen
        screenBg.setSize(width, height);

        // Place the logo in the middle of the screen and 100 px up
        logo.setX((width - logo.getWidth()) / 2);
        logo.setY((height - logo.getHeight()) / 2 + 100);

        // Place the loading frame in the middle of the screen
        loadingFrame.setX((stage.getWidth() - loadingFrame.getWidth()) / 2);
        loadingFrame.setY((stage.getHeight() - loadingFrame.getHeight()) / 2);

        // Place the loading bar at the same spot as the frame, adjusted a few px
        loadingBar.setX(loadingFrame.getX() + 15);
        loadingBar.setY(loadingFrame.getY() + 5);

        // Place the image that will hide the bar on top of the bar, adjusted a few px
        loadingBarHidden.setX(loadingBar.getX() + 35);
        loadingBarHidden.setY(loadingBar.getY() - 3);
        // The start position and how far to move the hidden loading bar
        startX = loadingBarHidden.getX();
        endX = 440;

        // The rest of the hidden bar
        loadingBg.setSize(450, 50);
        loadingBg.setX(loadingBarHidden.getX() + 30);
        loadingBg.setY(loadingBarHidden.getY() + 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // Clear the screen
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (game.manager.update()) { // Load some, will return true if done loading
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) { // If the screen is touched after the game is done loading, go to the main menu screen
                game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
            }
        }

        // Interpolate the percentage to make it more smooth
        percent = Interpolation.linear.apply(percent, game.manager.getProgress(), 0.1f);

        // Update positions (and size) to match the percentage
        loadingBarHidden.setX(startX + endX * percent);
        loadingBg.setX(loadingBarHidden.getX() + 30);
        loadingBg.setWidth(450 - 450 * percent);
        loadingBg.invalidate();

        // Show the loading screen
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {}

    @Override
    public void resume () {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // Dispose the loading assets as we no longer need them
        game.manager.unload("data/images-ui/loading/loading.pack");
    }
}
```

I need to load the screen then load my assets on this `Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager())` since it is what is causing a black screen. The problem is my screen loads after loading the assets hence this makes my loading screen to be of no use. How can I load this method after the screen has rendered?

Comment: Show your `Assets.instance.init` method.

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understood your code and requirement correctly, but I think you shouldn't load assets in the init method, but rather by calling game.manager.load for each asset. This way you could load the loading screen resources first, then call game.manager.finishLoading(); and finally  load the rest of the resources while the loading screen is being displayed. Although arguably it's a less elegant solution then loading everything in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I do need to use Assets class which I load the AssetManager from `game`. If you mean loading every single asset I am doing it using game.manager that is the argument for my Assets constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `finishLoading` call from your init method. That should do it. `finishLoading` forces the assets to finish loading immediately which is not what you want here. Calling `update` on it repeatedly, which you are already doing is the way to load assets asynchronously.

Here's a general structure for how it could be done. Call all the `load` methods on the asset manager before it ever gets to the `render` method. Then call update repeatedly until everything is loaded. Then get references to the assets before continuing.

```
private boolean loadComplete;

public void show(){
    //...
    loadComplete = false;
}

private void init(AssetManager assetManager){
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
    assetManager.load(/*whatever*/);
    assetManager.load(/*whatever*/);
    assetManager.load(/*whatever*/);
}

private void onAssetsLoaded(){
    loadComplete = true;
    myAtlas = assetManager.get("myAtlas.json", TextureAtlas.class);
    //and so on
}

public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //load one asset at a time per frame until loading is complete
    if (assetManager == null || !assetManager.update()){
        //maybe draw a load screen image that's not a texture that's being managed 
        //by the assetManager. You could even play an animation. Otherwise, 
        //you can leave the screen blank.

        return;
    }

    //will only get here when asset manager is done. The first time, you still
    //need to get references to its assets
    if (!loadComplete)
        onAssetsLoaded();

    //the rest of you render method. Everything below here only happens after assets are loaded and asset references have been aquired

}
```

Comment: Doing this will cause the assetManager to try and `get()` the TextureAtlas before its loaded. How am I supposed to implement this without the error?

Comment: @Zack Use isLoaded method. The only question is if you have the resources for your loading screen already. My understanding was, that you don't, because you load everything together (resources for the loading screen and the next screen) and in my comment I was referring to this situation, but maybe I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong `'isLoaded()` checks if an Asset File is loaded but here I need to wait for multiple assets to load. How do you think I can do that?

Comment: @Zack I was thinking about calling isLoaded() for every needed resource and waiting until every check returns true. If you want to wait until everything is loaded check if update() returns true or getProgress() is 1.

Comment: @Zack I added an example.

Answer (score -1):

After trying so many recommended solutions, I finally managed to fix this problem thanks to [this blog post](http://gigagrand.com/blog/?p=42)

I used a callback which displays an android framelayout with an image as the assets load asynchronously.